# Color sequence recognition using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

What could be the possible machine vision solution for correct color recognition using opencv?

I must check if the color sequence of the connector bellow is correct.
Is it better to use color regonition technique or pattern match technique? 
Is there any better approach to solve this?

In the image bellow is connector with colored wires, how to check correct sequence of wires?

[image]

Comment: if it is always this order of colors and in this position, you can try inRange function (colors may vary a little bit) several times and compare the position of the majority of those pixels. also you can try to detect the lines and get colors for each line.

Comment: One idea: if you determine the location of the connector at the top, then you know that you can just drop down and select a smaller ROI containing just the wires. Additionally, if you determine the scale of the connector, then you can split that ROI into regions based on the number of wires, and separate out each wire like that. Then you'll have them in order and multiple small images with just a single strip of wire in them, and the color detection should be easy then.

Comment: Alexander Reynolds : You mean something like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0zzlrbpllrgklmf/Brez%20naslova.png?dl=0

Comment: api55: Ok..thats a great function. So how first I think I should make better contrast of colored wires if I wana check each color separatelly. The problem here is that if I make black bacground then black wires will not be seen, also this is similar for white background - white wire will not be seen... And other issue that I don't know how to solve is : What algoritm should I use in c++ to determine color sequence...

Answer (score 4):

I suggest doing following steps (with simple code ilustration):

1. converting to L*a*b color space;

   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space/

   `cv::cvtColor(img,img,CV_BGR2Lab);`
2. take subimage which contains only wires

   `img = img(cv::Rect(x,y,width,height)); // detect wires`

[image]

3. compute mean values for each column and get 1D vector of values

   ```
   std::vector<cv::Vec3f> aggregatedVector;
   for(int i=0;i<img.cols;i++)
   {
     cv::Vec3f sum = cv::Vec3f(0,0,0);
     for(int j=0;j<img.rows;j++)
     {
       sum[0]+= img.at<Vecb>(j,i)[0]);
       sum[1]+= img.at<Vecb>(j,i)[1];
       sum[2]+= img.at<Vecb>(j,i)[2];
     }
     sum = sum/img.rows;
     aggregatedVector.push_back(sum);
   }
   ```
4. extract uniform fields using, for example gradient and get vector with 20 
    values

   ```
   std::vector<Vec3f> fields
   cv::Vec3f mean = 0;
   int counter =0;
   for(int i=0;i<aggregatedVector.size();i++)
      {
        mean+= aggregatedVector[i];
        if(cv::norm(aggregatedVector[i+1] - aggregatedVector[i]) > /*thresh here */
           {
             fields.push_back(mean/(double)counter);
             mean = cv::Vec3f(0,0,0);
             counter=0;
           }
         counter++
      }
   ```
5. compute vector of color distances between calculated vector and reference

   ```
     double totalError = 0;
     for(int i=0;i<fields.size();i++)
        {
           totalError+= cv::mean(reference[i]-fields[i]);
        }
   ```

   Then you can make decision based on error vector values. Have fun!

Comment: Thank you for response. This looks like completely new approach for me. Can I kindly ask you for additional information about this approach? I don't know much of any of this 1-5 point :)

Comment: @jok23 I added simple source code for algorithm steps ilustration.

Comment: @KamilSzelag all of your posts the past day have been excellent, excited to have you around here.

Comment: Kamil that sound interesting, still I don't understand what exactly you are doing at point 4??

Comment: @jok23 I'm reducing dimensionality of problem -> from 2d to 1d

Comment: So.. how can I define threshold (point 4) and how to define reference[i] in point 5? Still cannot visualize everything...

Comment: It would be vector {red,white,black,white,yellow,white ... } , where red,black,white are color reference values

Comment: So: Point 4: /*thresh here */ should be vector{red,white,black,white,yellow,white ... } values, and Point 5: reference[i] is also vector of values from reference image? So I should take "Golden sample" -> image where wires are ordered in correct order and then use this "Golden sample" values to define variable: reference[i] ?

Comment: Something like that

Comment: POINT 4: I still don't understand that /* Thresh here */ should be a vector? isnt it just value? 'if(cv::norm(aggregatedVector[i+1] - aggregatedVector[i]) > /*thresh here */' difference of norm returns me double value, so threshold should be also define as double??

Comment: Also when I run code above it gives me an ERROR saying: ![IMG](http://shrani.si/f/39/F6/1zLhUt57/untitled.png).