# Algorithm to count stripes in a Image

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing

**SITUATION**

I need to detect and count with my iPad these stripes in the image:

[image]

I'm using OpenCV and after convert the image in grayscale and equalize the histogram I obtain this picture:

[image]

To count the stripes I check when the color is below a certain value (usually 80 in grayscale).

**PROBLEM**

Sometimes I have some light disturb and I obtain this image:

[image]

I can see that there are only 2 stripes , because the third is probably some disturb and it's not defined, but my algorithm detect 3 stripes, because the color is under my limit (80). I can't decrease the limit or I'll not able to detect stripes in other images.

Someone have some suggest to how implements an algorithm that detects 3 stripes in the first image and 2 stripes in the second? Maybe not base on a color limit but on something different like a derivative.

Even only ideas, different language or pseudo-code are accepted

Comment: derivative sounds like a good idea, you can try doing it, checking for a contrast edges instead of darker color. I mean, the 'real' stripe has a short and very contrast edge, yet the 'false' stripe's edges are washed out a lot. So probably a color difference on small sections could give you more information than just color brightness

Comment: I'll try but the problem is that not always there is a high contrast edge (like in the first picture, if you see the third stripe there is white -> gray -> black  -> gray). How can I detect if the edge is short o if it is washed out a lot? Do you have suggests on the logic of the algorithms?

Comment: I mean, you can approximate this picture as a function with a spline and then look for local extremums considering not only height/deep of the extremum but also the sharpness of the pike, using a gradient (or as your function is most likely to vary on one variable - its numeric derivative). Conceptually there's no real difference from what you are doing right now but this probably will get you more accurate results due to derivative's limit nature

Comment: Project and threshold, then you can get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfjnN.png)

Comment: Use adaptive thresholding with big filter size. That'll do. Something like [This.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47631839/how-to-count-the-number-of-steel-rods-in-a-video/47634547#47634547). but with bigger kernel. Change 11 to 51 in that function

Answer (score 0):

I propose using following algorithm:

1. Make single column image with mean values of each row.
2. Go through column and calculate derivative.
3. Find local minimas and maximas (derivative similar to 0)
4. Since stripes are distributed regularly, you can find pattern (equal dustance between minimas)
5. Count largest pattern found size

EDIT: I described similar algorithm for colors. You can use minimas and maximas loaction in similar way

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46446002/8682088

If you have any questions, leave a comment.

Have fun coding!